# How to get the vertices from an edge using igraph in python?

Tags: python, igraph, vertex, edges

I am looping through the edges of a graph with:

```
 for es in graph.es:
         .... 
         # v = []
         # v = es.vertices()?
         ...
```

What method can I use to get the source and the target vertices for each edge?

Comment: [`source`, `target`, and `tuple` look relevant.](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Edge-class.html)

Comment: yes - es.source and es.target do the job;

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are the very basic functionalities of igraph, described [here](https://igraph.org/python/tutorial/0.9.8/tutorial.html) thoroughly.
If you iterate the `<EdgeSeq>` object (`graph.es`), you will go through all `<Edge>` objects (here `edge`). `<Edge>` has properties `source` and `target`. These are vertex ids, simply integers. You can get the corresponding `<Vertex>` object by `graph.vs[]`:

```
for edge in graph.es:
  source_vertex_id = edge.source
  target_vertex_id = edge.target
  source_vertex = graph.vs[source_vertex_id]
  target_vertex = graph.vs[target_vertex_id]
  # using get_eid() you can do the opposite:
  same_edge_id = graph.get_eid(source_vertex_id, target_vertex_id)
  same_edge = graph.es[same_edge_id]
  # by .index you get the id from the Vertex or Edge object:
  source_vertex.index == source_vertex_id
  # True
  edge.index == same_edge_id
  # True
```

Be aware if you have directed graph, otherwise source and target are simply two equivalent endpoints. With directed graphs you may use `error = False` with `get_eid()`, which then returns `-1` in case there is no edge in the given direction between the vertices.

Comment: what if I have a large graph and do not want to go through a for loop but just want the vertices that have a certain degree

Comment: you can do either `graph.vs[(i for i, d in enumerate(graph.vs.degree()) if d > 3)]` or `graph.vs[(v.index for v in graph.vs if v.degree() > 3)]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one simple way to get edge information from an igraph object using built-in function `get.data.frame()` in **R** (I did not notice the question was asking about python, sorry):

```
edges_data_frame <- get.data.frame(your_igraph, what = "edges")
```

The first two columns of `edges_data_frame` will be "from" and "to". The following columns will be other attributes of the edges if there are.